# Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello for every one I have some problems in android sudio

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update D:\flutter-programing\kidsgame\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How can I make it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iZuH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this change  as shown in below image
[image]

Comment: I tried but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

So this was requirement with the new flutter update. Heres what you need to change.
From:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

To:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

You are simply needing to change the version number to the latest version available on Kotlin's website. Which as of t0day should be what i've put above. Just run flutter clean and flutter pub get after this and youre done.